# PouchDB Chrome Console Error when Opening a Connection

Tags: google-chrome, pouchdb

I am using PouchDB with MVC. I open my connection via javascript like so:

```
var db = new PouchDB("MillersDB");
```

I noticed in Chrome's console the following error always appears immediately:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
blob:http%3A//localhost%3A51662/56b3fda3-cbad-4023-b8b1-4f3d3942d302
```

I'm not sure what's causing this, or if there is an option to disable the feature it is trying to use.  I am interested in storing locally, and I want pouchDB to do it's magic and make the decision of what db to use based on the browser. I disabled all my chrome extensions in case it was related to one of those.  Everything seems to work fine even with the error...it's more of an annoyance.  I opened up my page in IE and didn't see it.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Nope.  No solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a test to see if chrome supports a feature so the 404 is expected, annoyingly there is no way to suppress the warning (though there is an issue open in Firefox). We are probably going to start logging messages to the console explaining the "errors" in the mean time because this is a really common issue.

Answer (score 4):

That is PouchDB detecting broken blob URL support in Chrome. It's not an error, so nothing to worry about. :)